# How to generate and add gridview at runtime in android using java?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gridview

here i have created gridview gridView1 in xml and displaying static data in it.

**Q.1**  Is it possible to generate and add gridview at runtime to my andoid app  maybe in a scrollviwe or linear layout?

**Q.2** How to change font size of data displayed in gridview?

Please help

```
String[] mydata = new String[] { 
                    "Name", "Phone", 
                    "Mangesh", "63737377", 
                    "Rajnish", "63737344", 
                    "Disha", "63737399",
                    "Ashwin", "63737312"};

          gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , mydata);
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to use fragments in Android to do this. you can put a placeholder component in our layout and swap it with a fragment on create of an activity. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You would declare your layout mylayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainBack"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridViewFrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You want to replace `FrameLayout` from the above layout with myfragment.xml (for example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Then in your code, in the appropriate place call a method to swap out the FrameLayout and replace it with your GridView (not sure if you can do it in other places)

```
private void attachGridViewFragment(int headerFrag) {
    FragmentManager fragMgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction xact = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
    try {
        if (findViewById(headerFrag) != null) {
            Resources res = getResources();
            String title = res.getString(R.string.app_icon_name);
            xact.replace(headerFrag, new GridViewFragment(title, true, true), HEADER_FRAGMENT_TAG).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e("MyActivityName", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

You will of course have to write the `GridViewFragment` class... that much you can just Google on [how to use fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

But effectively you have to create a class `GridViewFragment` (for example) that extends `Fragment`.